# PowerShell IO large files without loading everything to memory

Tags: powershell, csv, file-io

I have a scenario where I need to edit very large files and the end result is rather simple, but achieving it has become a bit of a drag on my computer and memory. Due to downstream systems, I cannot load a duplicate file (according to a computed hash) twice. My workaround has been to move the first actual line/record to the end of the file without changing anything else. This method (shown below in Method 1) works great for files that are small enough, but now I have files that are extremely large. So I began working on Method 2 below, but I haven't quite figured out how to *stream* lines from an input file into an output file.

```
#Method 1
$Prefix = Read-Host -Prompt "What do you want to use as the prefix for the updated file names? (The number 1 is the default)"
If ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Prefix)){$Prefix = '1_'}
If($Prefix[-1] -ne '_'){$Prefix = "$($Prefix)_"}
$files = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PWD -Filter '*.csv' -File)
Foreach ($inputFile in $files){
    $A = Get-Content $inputFile
    $Header = $A[0]
    $Data = $A[2..($A.Count-1)]
    $Footer = $A[1]
    $Header, $Data, $Footer | Add-Content -LiteralPath "$($inputFile.DirectoryName)\$($Prefix)$($inputFile.BaseName).csv"
}
```

```
#Work-in-progress Method 2
$inputFile = "\Input.csv"
$outputFile = "\Output.csv"

#Create StringReader
$sr = [System.IO.StringReader]::New((Get-Content $inputFile -Raw))

#Create StringWriter
$sw = [System.IO.StringWriter]::New()

#Write the Header
$sw.Write($sr.ReadLine())

#Get the first actual record as a string
$lastLine = $sr.ReadLine()

#Write the rest of the lines
$sw.Write($sr.ReadToEnd())

#Add the final line
$sw.Write($lastLine)

#Write everything to the outputFile
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($outputFile, $sw.ToString())

Get-Content:
Line |
   5 |  $sr = [System.IO.StringReader]::New((Get-Content $inputFile -Raw))
     |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
MethodInvocationException:
Line |
   5 |  $sr = [System.IO.StringReader]::New((Get-Content $inputFile -Raw))
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')"
```

I'm having a bit of trouble comprehending the difference between a `StringWriter` itself and a `StringBuilder`, for example - why would I choose to use the `StringWriter` as I have rather than simply work with a `StringBuilder` directly? Most importantly though, the current iteration of Method 2 requires more memory than my system has and it isn't actually *streaming* the characters/lines/data from the input file to the output file. Are there built in methods for checking memory that I'm overlooking, or is there simply a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Have you considered doing something _other_ than transposing data from the beginning of the file to the end? Like, swapping either the first two or the last two lines? That would leave you with a much smaller portion of data that actually needs to be moved around...

Comment: Not sure why you're using a `StringReader` you're probably looking for `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` for _line-by-line_ processing

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - my understanding, rough as it may be, is that `TextReader` is an abstract class and is implemented with a `StreamReader` for *universal* reading/writing as long as you use the correct encoding. Since I'm working with strings, `StringReader` - in my mind - is a specific use case of a `StreamReader` that knows it is working with strings

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - The only reason I went with moving the first line to the end is that it worked well on smaller files and I might need to make the modifications more than once - so I don't want to be in a situation where I'm simply swapping the first two lines back and forth. Moving the first line to the bottom seemed like it gave me maximum flexibility because the file wouldn't match the original until I somehow managed to repeat the process X number of times (X being the total number of lines). Regardless though, I don't know how to do what you're proposing without the same issue I have

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by your comment, by doing `Get-Content $inputFile -Raw` you're loading the entire content in memory and feeding it to the `StringReader`. If you want to process line by line and keep memory usage as low as possible then use a `StreamReader`.

Comment: Ah - I see...yes, my understanding of `StreamReader` and `StringReader` was definitely incorrect. Ok - dumb question, but it took my awhile to get this far. I see how it works now

Comment: Appending files to an existing file takes time  So using one stream writer will definitely speed results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code would look using [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0) and [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-7.0):

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PWD -Filter '*.csv' -File | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $path   = "$($_.DirectoryName)\$Prefix$($_.BaseName).csv"
        $writer = [IO.StreamWriter] $path
        $stream = $_.OpenRead()
        $reader = [IO.StreamReader] $stream
        $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine()) # => This is header
        $footer = $reader.ReadLine()
        while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
            $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine())
        }
        $writer.WriteLine($footer)
    }
    finally {
        $stream, $reader, $writer | ForEach-Object Dispose
    }
}
```

This method will keep memory usage as low as possible and will be as efficient as it gets.

Comment: please note that the line to move is the first record which would be the second file line, not the csv header which is the first file line.

Comment: thank you @Gregory, didn't notice it, I'm surprised OP accepted my answer and didn't let me know about this.

Comment: @immobile2 no need to apologize haha it was my bad after all

Comment: @immobile2 there isn't any, but, when using APIs that take a handle on the file like `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` you wan to make sure they're disposed properly hence why using `finally` is always the recommended approach

Comment: Got it, that makes sense as well because I think there are times when the `-End` block isn't processed in PowerShell - thank you

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing of the [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) is that it streams by nature.
*If correctly used*, meaning:

- Do not assign any pipeline results to a variable and
- Do not use parenthesis

As that will choke the pipeline.

In your case:

```
$Prefix = Read-Host -Prompt "What do you want to use as the prefix for the updated file names? (The number 1 is the default)"
If ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Prefix)){$Prefix = '1_'}
If($Prefix[-1] -ne '_'){$Prefix = "$($Prefix)_"}

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PWD -Filter '*.csv' -File |
Import-Csv |ForEach-Object -Begin { $Index = 0 } -Process {
    if ($Index++) { $_ } else { $Footer = $_ }
} -End { $Footer } |
Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$($inputFile.DirectoryName)\$($Prefix)$($inputFile.BaseName).csv"
```

Comment: Ha - I just realized why the `Index++` works, you're just checking if it is line 1, but could also move other lines around. Slick. I'll need to test your answer a little more, but it definitely works and is a great example of making the pipeline do the work. The only other thing though is adding `-PipelineVariable inputFile` prior to `Import-Csv`, otherwise the names at the end are referencing a non-existent variable. `GCI -filter '*.csv' -PipelineVariable inputFile | Import-Csv |...`

Comment: Pardon the shorthand for the comments only, but this is the only working version of your script that I can get to work. I remember having issues with this in the past and I always get confused on which cmdlets intrinsically do a ForEach vs. needing to specify, but `Import-Csv` I think you need to be explicit: `GCI -LiteralPath $PWD -Filter '*.csv' -File -PipelineVariable inputFile | %{$_ | Import-Csv | ForEach-Object {$Index=0}{if($Index++){$_}Else{$Footer=$_}}{$Footer} | Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$($inputFile.DirectoryName)\$($Prefix)$($inputFile.BaseName).csv"}`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd need to go a bit faster on many larger files, and you know for certain that your csv data is clean, you could also use the binary `IO.FileStream`.

Basically the below example takes a core sample off the top of the file, scans for the header and footer lines. Then writes the header, dumps the remainder of the sample, and uses the stream class's CopyTo instead of PowerShell's while loop to get the speed boost, and finally writes the footer.

```
#asuming that .csv file lines end with CRLF ie bytes 13,10
# things go terribly wrong if this is not true
[byte]$ByteCR = 13 # 0D
[byte]$ByteLF = 10 # 0A
function Find-OffsetPastNextEOL{
   param([System.Collections.IEnumerator]$enu)
   $QuotedState = $false #ToDo: csv files can possibly have multiple lines per record
   $CRLF_found  = $false
   $count = 0
   while($enu.MoveNext() -and !$CRLF_found){ #expected to be a lot less iterations than the number of lines in the file
      $count++
      if($enu.Current -eq $ByteCR -and $enu.MoveNext()){
         $count++
         $CRLF_found = $enu.Current -eq $ByteLF
      }
   }
   return $count
}
function Test-EndOfFileHasEOL{
   param([System.IO.FileStream]$read)
   $null = $read.Seek(-2,'End')
   return $read.ReadByte() -eq $ByteCR -and $read.ReadByte() -eq $ByteLF
}

$BufferSize = 100mb
$SampleSize =   1mb #idealy something just big enough to make sure you get the first two lines of every file
$SampleWithHeadAndFoot = new-object byte[] $SampleSize
Foreach ($inputFile in $files){
   try{
#[IO.FileStream]::new(($IWantThis=$FullPath),($InorderTo='Open'),($IWill='Read'),($AtTheSameTimeOthersCan='Read'),($BytesAtOnce=$BufferSize))

      $ReadFilePath  = $inputFile.FullName
      $read  = [IO.FileStream]::new($ReadFilePath ,'Open'  ,'Read' ,'Read',$BufferSize)

      $WriteFilePath = $ReadFilePath -Replace ($inputFile.Name+'$'),"$Prefix`$0"
      $write = [IO.FileStream]::new($WriteFilePath,'Append','Write','None',$BufferSize)

      $TotalBytesSampled = $read.Read($SampleWithHeadAndFoot, 0, $SampleSize)
      #ToDo: check for BOM or other indicators that the csv data is one-byte ASCII or UTF8

      $enu = $SampleWithHeadAndFoot.GetEnumerator()
      $HeaderLength = 0 + (Find-OffsetPastNextEOL $enu)
      $FooterLength = 1 + (Find-OffsetPastNextEOL $enu)
      $DataStartPosition = $HeaderLength + $FooterLength
      $OversampleLength  = $TotalBytesSampled - ($HeaderLength + $FooterLength)

      $write.Write($SampleWithHeadAndFoot,0,$HeaderLength)             #write the header from the sample
      if($DataStartPosition -lt $TotalBytesSampled - 1){               #flush the sample data after the first record
         $write.Write($SampleWithHeadAndFoot,$DataStartPosition,$OversampleLength)
      }
      $read.CopyTo($write,$BufferSize)                                 #flush the rest of the data still in the read stream
      if(!(Test-EndOfFileHasEOL $read)){                               #inject CRLF if EOF didn't already have one
         $write.WriteByte($ByteCR)
         $write.WriteByte($ByteLF)
      }
      $write.Write($SampleWithHeadAndFoot,$HeaderLength,$FooterLength) #write the first record as the footer
   }finally{
      $read.Dispose()
      $write.Dispose()
   }
}
```

I manually tested with the below setup, but you'll likely want to make a few modifications for production code to make it a bit more robust against csv data found in the wild.

```
PS> sc xx.csv -Value @"
this is a header`r
this was line 1`r
this was line 2`r
this was line 3`r
this was line 4`r
this was line 5
"@ -Encoding utf8 -NoNewLine

PS> $Prefix     = '1_'
PS> $files      = ls xx.csv
PS> $SampleSize = 40

PS> Format-Hex .\xx.csv

           Path: .\xx.csv

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   EF BB BF 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 68 65 61  ï»¿this is a hea
00000010   64 65 72 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73 20 6C 69  der..this was li
00000020   6E 65 20 31 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73 20 6C  ne 1..this was l
00000030   69 6E 65 20 32 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73 20  ine 2..this was
00000040   6C 69 6E 65 20 33 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73  line 3..this was
00000050   20 6C 69 6E 65 20 34 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61   line 4..this wa
00000060   73 20 6C 69 6E 65 20 35                          s line 5

PS> Format-Hex .\1_xx.csv

           Path: .\1_xx.csv

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   EF BB BF 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 68 65 61  ï»¿this is a hea
00000010   64 65 72 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73 20 6C 69  der..this was li
00000020   6E 65 20 32 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73 20 6C  ne 2..this was l
00000030   69 6E 65 20 33 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73 20  ine 3..this was
00000040   6C 69 6E 65 20 34 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61 73  line 4..this was
00000050   20 6C 69 6E 65 20 35 0D 0A 74 68 69 73 20 77 61   line 5..this wa
00000060   73 20 6C 69 6E 65 20 31 0D 0A                    s line 1..
```

Comment: This is going to take me awhile to analyze and understand, but testing it should be rather straightforward. Thank you for the great analysis!

Comment: @immobile2 some places you'll run into hiccups are when the csv isn't ASCII or UTF8, or the EOL isn't always CRLF, or if either the first record or header has a quoted field with CRLF. When reviewing the csv data `get-content -encoding byte -totalcount 200` and `| format-hex -encoding utf8` are your friends